# mod_mono-2.10 barking on targetFramework in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, mod-mono, osx-mavericks

Yesterday I upgraded to OSX Mavericks and needed to reinstall mod_mono.

All my .net websites targeting asp.net 4.0 now bark:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Error deserializing configuration section compilation: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

So I removed the `'targetFramework="4.0"` attribute from the compilation line.

This results in **another problem**:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Error deserializing configuration section pages: Unrecognized attribute 'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion'.

So I then remove `'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"'` from the pages line and got:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Error deserializing configuration section pages: Unrecognized attribute 'clientIDMode'.

As the `'clientIdMode="AutoID"'` is the only attribute left on the files node, I just completely removed the node.

Then it gets a `System.TypeLoadException`.

I haven't bothered to look into that problem. These sites were running perfectly well before the update, so there must be some configuration thing that I missed out.

`AFAIKT` I run the latest stable versions of all involved software.

Just intrigued by the fact that the youngest mod_mono I found [here](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mod_mono/), dates from **'14-Feb-2011 20:39'**.

Please advise,

guivho.

Comment: what version of Mono are you using?

Comment: Mono framework 3.2.0; 
mod_mono-2.10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this resolved using instructions at
http://www.mono-project.com/AutoHosting

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/AutoHosting is a discussion on the Apache or mod_mono config.  The question relates to the web.config file within a site, which is a completely different issue, hence this link, beyond pointing to the mono-project, is completely unhelpful